# Performatic way to apply multiple operations to a single dataframe in a function?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big dataframe in a ETL operation, that needs to be as performatic as possible.

I have written a simple function to replace all null values ('', nans, empty lists and dicts) to None (because they will be inserted into Postgres databases):

```
    def set_dfnulls_as_none(data):

        start = timeit.default_timer()

        data = data.replace({np.nan: None})
        data = data.replace({'': None})
        data = data.replace({np.isnan: None})
        data = data.mask(data.applymap(type).eq(list) &
                 ~data.astype(bool), other=None)
        data = data.mask(data.applymap(type).eq(dict) &
                 ~data.astype(bool), other=None)

        stop = timeit.default_timer()
        print('Time: ', stop - start)

        return data
```

What i don't know how to do, is how to get this code to be more performatic. I think i can apply the same functions, but at the "same" time? Without assigning it to a new dataframe at each function? Any suggestions? Any improvement to this time would be excellent!

## EDIT

Example data:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['test', 'test'],
'B': ['', ''],
'C': [{},{}],
'D': [[], []],
'E': ['2020-03-11', '2020-03-11'],
'F': [[],[]]})

data:
A      B    C   D   E           F
test        {}  []  2020-03-11  []
test        {}  []  2020-03-11  []
```

Output after function:

```
A       B       C       D       E           F
test    None    None    None    2020-03-11  None
test    None    None    None    2020-03-11  None

execution time: 0.019766
```

Comment: can you provide additional information? current runtime, desired runtime, example dataframe

Comment: Additioned an small sample of the data that i get and the execution time. I don't have a target time, any improvement would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```py
def to_None(df):
    df = df.astype(object)
    df[(df != df) | (df.applymap(type).isin({str, list, dict}) & ~df.astype(bool))] = None
    return df
```

Example:

```py
# modified to include some Falsy but legit values:
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['test', 'test'],
    'B': ['', ''],
    'C': [{},{}],
    'D': [[], []],
    'E': ['2020-03-11', '2020-03-11'],
    'F': [[],[]],
    'G': [0,2],
    'H': [True, False],
    'I': [0.0,2.0],
})

>>> to_None(data)
      A     B     C     D           E     F  G      H  I
0  test  None  None  None  2020-03-11  None  0   True  0
1  test  None  None  None  2020-03-11  None  2  False  2
```

**Performance**

```py
%timeit to_None(data)
3.56 ms ± 22.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Both your and erap129 answers are very helpful! I will try both in staging and give a feedback here after. Thanks! :)

Comment: Mmh, there is a problem: other values that are Falsy become `None` (e.g.: 0, 0.0, False, ...)

Comment: Thanks, Pierre! Both you and erap functions were great and pretty identical in performance. Both much faster than my own. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

cut down to a cleaner function call and cut time by half more or less.

```
import timeit
import timeit
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [{'inner_dict': 777}, {}, np.nan, ''],
                   'b': [4, [1, 2, 3], [], np.nan]})
large_df = pd.concat([df] * 100000)


def set_dfnulls_as_none(data):
    data = data.replace({np.nan: None})
    data = data.replace({'': None})
    data = data.replace({np.isnan: None})
    data = data.mask(data.applymap(type).eq(list) & ~data.astype(bool), other=None)
    data = data.mask(data.applymap(type).eq(dict) & ~data.astype(bool), other=None)
    return data


def set_dfnulls_as_none_improved(data):
    data = data.mask(((data.applymap(type).isin([list, dict]) & ~data.astype(bool)) |
                      (data == '') | (data.isna())),
                     other=None)
    return data


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(f'new function runtime: '
          f'{timeit.timeit("set_dfnulls_as_none_improved(large_df)", "from __main__ import set_dfnulls_as_none_improved, large_df", number=100)}')
    print(f'old function runtime: '
          f'{timeit.timeit("set_dfnulls_as_none(large_df)", "from __main__ import set_dfnulls_as_none, large_df", number=100)}')
```

output:

```
new function runtime: 15.580043100000001
old function runtime: 35.6438879
```

Comment: Both your and Pìerre D answers are very helpful! I will try both in staging and give a feedback here after. Thanks! :)